# How to change the address of a variable with functions?

Tags: c, memory-address

I am trying to change the address of a certain variable using a function, but i don't know the way to do this... However this is my go:

```
void address (int* x, int* y)
{
    x = y;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 2;
    int y = 4;

    address(&x, &y);
    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want to do what? Make `x` and `y` be at the same address?

Comment: @yano. Looks like he's trying to change the address without moving the variable :)

Comment: What do you mean "change the address"? The address is an abstraction of a physical property. There is not much you can do to change it as phrased. Please be much much much more clear.

Comment: Yes i would like to make x's address equal to y.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Heh, not quite sure. John Dale Sounds impossible to me. It sounds like you're saying "I want this apple and orange to occupy exactly the same space in the universe". Perhaps some physicist can dispute me, but that's impossible. `x` and `y` are two different things, they can't occupy the same space. If they occupy the same space, they are the same thing and all you need is `x`. Now, if you want a pointer/reference to `x`, that's different.

Comment: It's impossible. because it's managed by compiler. if you want result of `printf("%d", x);` become `4`, `*x = *y;` instead of `x = y;`.

Comment: I'd like to make x's pointer equal to y's pointer, i hope you understand it now lol

Comment: The code does a `printf("%d", x);` to show the _value_ of `x`.  So certainly OP does not want to "change the address of a variable", but to change the _value_ of `x`.

Comment: @chux I don't know if we can say with any certainty what OP wants ;)

Comment: @JohnDale You cannot do that, actually what are you trying to do or are you just trying to understand pointers, programming , c etc?

Comment: Are you trying to change the value at a given address to the value at a different address as it seems? In that case, I suggest editing your question significantly.

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to change the address of a certain variable using a function

The answer to this is: you cannot. As pointed out in the comments, `the address is an abstraction of a physical property`. The variables hold space in memory, and only one variable can occupy a given space (on architectures that exist today).

If you mean that you want to change the value of two variables which hold addresses (also known as `pointers`) to hold different values, your variables will need to be declared as pointers, and your function will need to accept pointers-to-pointers. For example:

```
void address (int** x, int** y)
{
    *x = *y;
}

int main(void)
{
   int x = 2;
   int y = 4;

   int *px = &x; // px points to x
   int *py = &y; // py points to y

   address(&px, &py);
   printf("%d", px);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i've been looking for! :)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want

```
void address (int* x, int* y)
{
    *x = *y;
}
```

even though the wording of your question is very poor.

If I have misunderstood and you really are expecting to be able to change the address of a variable, you cannot. The address of a variable is not a piece of information attached to the variable that can be changed. The address of the variable *is* the variable. The name of it is just a human convenience.

More answer

the x and y in main are ints at say 0x1234 and 0x1236 you then call    your function. It happens to have 2 args called x and y , these are    not really associated with x and y in main. These args are pointers    to ints, the contain the address of 2 ints. IN your case mains' x and    y.

I will call mains x and y main.x and main.y. I will call the funcs x and y func.x and func.y

So  func.x = 0x1234 and func.y = 0x1236. You can do what ever you like with these, you did

```
func.x = func.y
```

OK so now the original value of func.x is lost and it has the the value of func.y. Both now have the address of main.y. Fine, this does change any aspect of main.x and main.y

Juggling pointers around doesn't change the things they point at, it simply makes them point at different things

Think like this. In a C program

```
int x
```

Means allocate a variable thats 4 bytes long and remember its address for me, I will refer to that address as 'x'. IN the very early days of programming (old old assembler etc) you would have to program saying

```
thing at 0x1234 = 42;
thing at 0x1236 = thing at 0x1234 + 2;
```

etc. (You did actually say 'thing at' you had some cpu specific instruction , but its the same thing) , this is one of the main jobs of compilers, to allow you to call a region of memory 'count_of_mice' or 'size_of_planet', cos its really hard reading code that only has numbers

Comment: I don't know... when i debug and enter the function "address", i can see in the watches window under "locals" that 

x = 0x28ff18 
y = 0x28ff18

so it works, but not when i return to my main function. I would like this change to be carried over to my main function. Is it possible?

Comment: @JohnDale I have exapnded answer

Comment: Ah okay, thank you, so we are only changing the pointers here in your example right?

Answer (score 0):

The address of a variable is one of its identifying characteristics.  You cannot change the address of a variable any more than you can change the value of 1.

Or here's another analogy: suppose I write down my street address on a slip of paper, "99 JB Lane", and give it to you.  You can use the that paper help you visit my house.  You might even choose to change my house, say by raking the leaves.  Now suppose you blot out the "99" on the paper and replace it with "42".  You do not that way changed my actual house number, nor can you in that way make my house and my neighbors house be the same house.  If "42 JB Lane" happens to be a valid address, however, then you can use the paper to visit the house there.

The parameter values received by function `address()` are like the slip of paper I gave you: they tell the function where to find the values of two variables, and even enable it to modify those values, but the function cannot use them to change the *identity* of the variables whose values are stored at those addresses.